# How do i know number of cells between two points in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra

i have 2D array and give tow points p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) , is that any way to know number of cells between them ?

Comment: You need to define *cell* and *between*. Regardless of that, it sounds more like a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: i tag it as "linear-algebra" because i know it could be a math problem !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point `p(i,j)`, it's position in a matrix is equal to `i*width+j` where `width` is the width of the matrix. Hence the number of cells between two elemets is `abs((i1*width+j1) - (i2*width+j2))`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Albert this was very helpful